# schedule dynamic jobs using quartz, back up using hibernate(to schedule jobs from DB while server crash) in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

I want schedule jobs dynamically using quartz,hibernate and spring. And I need to have backup in table(DB), while dynamically schedule a job.

1. While server crash or stops, by using the table details, can I schedule all the list of jobs again?
2. is there any advantage of using hibernate(mysql) here?
3. please guide me how can i develop this requirement

Your help will greatly be appreciated. If possible, please provide me some examples as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer for all of these question is jdbcjobstore. Quartz providing more details in  documentation.
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/TutorialLesson09